# Sandboxing a program using WinAPI hooks

Tags: security, winapi, hook, sandbox, native-code

I'd like to sandbox a native code and use hooking of WinAPI and system functions to block or allow this program to perform some operations like reading/writing files, modify Windows registry, using an Internet connection. Is it a good and secure way to do so? How difficult would it be for that program to bypass such a security layer?

Comment: @Hans there exists a limited (though long) list of API functions, so with enough inspirations they can be hooked. Yes, there are ways to bypass the hooks, but sandboxing an average application is possible. There are applications/SDKs on the market that let you do this for any program turning it into sandboxed one. BoxedApp is one name that comes to my mind, but there are more available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to Hans, however if you are really into it then I can recommend [Easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/). I have personally used it successfully in Win XP, Vista and 7. I don't know how bypassable it is but other alternatives do exist - madSHI hooks, and, if you want to go the official way, try Detours from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked your questions and they all are related to the task that seems to be invalid from the very beginning, and here's why: you are trying to secure one application and you are ready to reinvent the wheel for this. There exist several approaches (and many ready-made solutions) to solve your problem. So instead of coding you need to look at existing solutions.

The approaches are:

1. use Windows permissions to restrict
   access of your application to
   resources
2. take take VMWare or Parallels or
   other virtualization platform and
   run your program there
3. take sandboxing SDK (such as
   BoxedApp) and "wrap" your
   application.

Answer (score 1):

Antivirus apps try to solve nearly the same problem, without much success.

1. You'd never know how even most common operations can be used.

2. There're syscalls, so the program doesn't have to use winapi at all.