# memory safety and security - sandboxing arbitrary program?

Tags: security, memory-management, sandbox, native-code

In some languages (Java, C# without unsafe code, ...) it is (should be) impossible to corrupt memory - no manual memory management, etc. This allows them to restrict resources (access to files, access to net, maximum memory usage, ...) to applications quite easily - e.g. Java applets (Java web start). It's sometimes called sandboxing.

My question is: is it possible with native programs (e.g. written in memory-unsafe language like C, C++; but without having source code)? I don't mean simple bypass-able sandbox, or anti-virus software.

I think about two possibilities:

- run application as different OS user, set restrictions for this user. Disadvantage - many users, for every combination of parameters, access rights?
- (somehow) limit (OS API) functions, that can be called
  I don't know if any of possibilities allow (at least in theory) in full protection, without possibility of bypass.

Edit: I'm interested more in theory - I don't care that e.g. some OS has some undocumented functions, or how to sandbox any application on given OS. For example, I want to sandbox application and allow only two functions: get char from console, put char to console. How is it possible to do it unbreakably, no possibility of bypassing?

Answers mentioned:

- Google Native Client, uses subset of x86 - in development, together with (possible?) PNaCl - portable native client
- full VM - obviously overkill, imagine tens of programs...

In other words, could native (unsafe memory access) code be used within restricted environment, e.g. in web browser, with 100% (at least in theory) security?

Edit2: **Google Native Client** is exactly what I would like - any language, safe or unsafe, run at native speed, sandbox, even in web browser. Everybody use whatever language you want, in web or on desktop.

Comment: Check out [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580667/sandboxing-a-program-using-winapi-hooks). I think the short answer is going to be. Yes its possible to place these restrictions by hooking API, however never without the possibility of bypass.

Comment: I'm interested only in options without possibility of bypass. I have read the question before posting this one, it's not the same, both question and answers differ.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read about Google's [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) which runs x86 code (and ARM code I believe now) in a sandbox.

Comment: interesting: does this mean that without special care (native client uses subset of x86 and must be compiled specifically for it) it is not possible, because program could e.g. corrupt OS memory?

Comment: Native client restricts the code entered into it primarily to ensure that the hosted code does not a) make direct OS calls b) modify its own code c) change its code alignment with a non-aligned call so as to invalidate these proofs or d) write to memory outside its sandbox. Native client's approach is only one of many, and does not rely on any OS features, but rather only relies on CPU features available on all OSes - this is why code modifications are mandatory.

Comment: interesting - so e.g. compiler, virtual machine, cannot be secured this way? It obviously changes itself.

Comment: x86 and x64, which are incompatible. An ARM system appears to be coming soon.

Comment: @peenut Runtime generated code could theoretically be verified and inserted through an appropriate API.

Comment: Yes, sounds great. I just hope it will be portable and actually works.

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much described [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) in your original question. There are [quite a few good videos](http://www.google.com/search?q=apparmor&tbo=p&tbm=vid&source=vgc&hl=en&aq=f) explaining it which I highly recommend watching.

Comment: +1 for mentioning interesting solution, however it's OS-specific, and not very general; anyway it shows that a lot is possible

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Yes. Difficult? Also yes. OS-dependent? Very yes.

Most modern OSes support various levels of process isolation that can be used to acheive what you want. The simplest approach is to simply attach a debugger and break on all system calls; then filter these calls in the debugger. This, however, is a large performance hit, and is difficult to make safe in the presence of multiple threads. It is also difficult to implement safely on OSes where the low-level syscall interface is not documented - such as Mac OS or Windows.

The Chrome browser folks have done a lot of work in this field. They've posted design docs for [Windows](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox), [Linux](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSandboxing) (in particular [the SUID sandbox](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandbox)), and [Mac OS X](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/osx-sandboxing-design). Their approach is effective but not totally foolproof - there may still be some minor information leaks between the outer OS and the guest application. In addition, some of the OSes require specific modifications to the guest program to be able to communicate out of the sandbox.

If some modification to the hosted application is acceptable, Google's [native client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) is worth a look. This restricts the compiler's code generation choices in such a way that the loader can prove that it doesn't do anything nasty. This obviously doesn't work on arbitrary executables, but it will get you the performance benefits of native code.

Finally, you can always simply run the program in question, plus an entire OS to itself, in an emulator. This approach is basically foolproof, but adds significant overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible IF the hardware provides mechanisms to restrict memory accesses. Desktop processors usually are equipped with an MMU and access levels, so the OS can employ these to deny access to any memory address a thread should not have access to.

Virtual memory is implemented by the very same means: any access to memory currently swapped out to disk is trapped, the memory fetched from disk and then the thread is continued. Virtualization takes it a little farther, because it also traps accesses to hardware registers.

All the OS really needs to do is properly use those features and it will be impossible for any code to break out of the sandbox. Of course this much easier said than practically applied. Mostly because the OS takes liberties if favor of performance, oversights in what certain OS calls can be used to do and last but not least bugs in the implementation.

Comment: does this mean that MMU and access levels (and bug-free implementation) is enough? can this be done within OS that does not directly support sandboxing, without virtualization?

Comment: That would depened on the specific hardware architecture. I'm not sure you can trap accesses to I/O registers on x86 without the virtualization features. The MMU can be used to achieve complete process separation, and in case of memory mapped I/O the MMU can trap access to the hardware registers as well. Still the OS needs to be designed for it, if it uses any shared address spaces for the sake of performance this compromises any sandboxing attempt.